# Python 3 multiprocessing seems to share resources

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an application framework running under Python 3.5.1 on aRHEL 6.5 Linux host. Here is a vastly simplified view of the logic:

```
baseclass.py:

class base(object):
    v = None
    w = None

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        return

    def a(self):
        self.w = perform_tasks(self.v)
        return

    def retw(self):
        return(self.w)

    def close(self):
        del(self.v)
        del(self.w)
        return

myotherclass.py:
import baseclass

class dostuff(object):
    bar = None
    b = None
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.bar = baseclass.base(b)
        return

    def fb(self):
        self.bar.a()
        do stuff
        self.b = self.bar.retw()
        bar.close()
        return

    def retb(self):
        return(self.b)

    def close(self):
        del(self.b)
        del(self.bar)
        return

app.py:
import multiprocessing as mp
import myotherclass

def client(conn):
    while True:
        foo = myotherclass.dostuff(conn.recv())
        foo.fb()
        baz = foo.retb()
        conn.send(baz)
        foo.close()
        del(foo)
    return

workers = []
for i in range(0, X):
    parent_conn, client_conn = mp.Pipe()
    worker = mp.Process(target=client, args=(client_conn))
    worker.start()
    workers.append([worker, parent_conn])

....
workers[0][1].send(somedata)
workers[1][1].send(somedata)
```

So when I start up `app.py`, it spawn off X number of children as separate processes and communicates with them using parent_conn and client_conn.

It then sends commands to the children telling them to do some work. The children happily do work and return their results.

However, it appears that all of the children are sharing the same instance of baseclass. What I'm seeing is this:

Child 1 and Child 2 start up. `app.py` sends signals to them to start processing.

Child 1 creates an instance of myotherclass.dostuff.

Child 2 creates an instance of myotherclass.dostuff.

Child 2 finishes slightly before Child 1, closes its instance of myotherclass.dostuff and deletes its reference, which causes Child 2's instance of dostuff to close and delete its reference to baseclass.

Child 1 immediately fails and throws an exception that reference to `NoneType` is not allowed.

To me, this should not happen as Child 1 and Child 2 are completely separate processes with separate PIDs. baseclass and myotherclass do not have any global variables that might cause contention, all the data they need are stored locally inside the class as "self." variables.

Why would all of the children be sharing the same base instance of a class?

Comment: show the exception

Comment: you are only calling `__init__` once, after your first `close` your object is broken.  Also is there a reason you are using class variables instead of instance variables?